# Content script unable to send messages via send.port.emit

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have encountered undocumented behaviour in an SDK extension I am currently working on and would appreciate help from the community to find either a fix or a way around it.

The problem only occurs when an HTML page **embedded in the extension** is opened in a tab, like so:

`tabs.open(data.url("html/test.html"));`

Note that `test.html` above would reside in `data/html` from the extension's root directory.

I'm injecting a content script and listening for messages emitted as given below:

```
tabs.once("open", function (tab) {
  var w = tab.attach({ contentScriptFile: [ data.url("js/embed.js") ]});

  w.port.once("init", function () {
    console.log("content script initialised");
  });
});
```

The content script, `data/js/embed.js`, contains the following:

```
console.log("attaching embedded script");
self.port.emit("init");
```

The problem is that if the content script is attached to a *data* HTML page (a page embedded in the extension), messages sent by the content script are **suppressed**.

It is absolutely crucial that my extension opens an embedded HTML page and is able to both receive from and send messages to the extension.  How can I overcome this limitation?

---

*I've created a tiny extension that reproduces the problem clearly.  You can find it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kytoxpj3l7nvd2l/test.zip?dl=1).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as pointed out [here](https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/content-script-unable-to-send-messages-via-send-port-emit/3922/2), is to emit the message in the `ready` event (and not `open`).

Answer (score 0):

Found a way of circumventing the limitation but it's rather hacky. It consists of grabbing the content window object of the tab and then relying on the Window's `postMessage` API.  Like so:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs"),
    self = require("sdk/self"),
    data = self.data,
    utils = require("sdk/tabs/utils"),
    {viewFor} = require("sdk/view/core");

tabs.once("ready", function (tab) {
  var window = utils.getTabContentWindow(viewFor(tab));
  window.addEventListener("message", function (ev) {
    console.log("message received: ", ev.data);
  });
});

tabs.open(data.url("html/test.html"));
```

Then in a script **loaded by the HTML page**, one would do something similar to:

`window.postMessage({ method: "init", state: true }, origin);`

I would still like to know why one can't use the native `self.port.emit` API though? Or why it **quietly** suppresses attempts at emitting messages.